# Pointer Arithmetic In C

Tags: c, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

Consider the following code fragment:

```
int (*p)[3];
int (*q)[3];

q = p;
q++;
printf("%d, %d\n", q, p);
printf("%d\n", q-p);
```

I know that pointer arithmetic is intelligent, meaning that the operation `q++` advances `q` enough bytes ahead to point to a next 3-integers-array, so it does not surprises me that the first print is '`12, 0`' which means that incrementing `q` made it larger in 12.

But the second print *does* surprises me. It prints 1!
So why would it print 1 instead of 12? it just puzzles me.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Like the `++` increment operator, the `-` subtraction operator with pointers also takes into account the size of the objects being pointed to. Specifically, the result returned is the number of bytes difference in the pointer values divided by the size of the pointed-to object (12, in your example). So the difference is 12 bytes, divided by size 12, or 1.

Comment: So there's no way to take two pointers and get their difference in bytes?

Comment: Cast the pointers to (char *) then you'll get the difference in bytes.

Comment: @Leif: Or just multiply the difference by sizeof(your_type).

Answer (score 4):

If you really want to know the difference cast each pointers to a (char*) and then to (int) and then subtract. That should give you the answer.

This code gives you the absolute value:

```
printf("%d\n", abs((int)((char*)q) - (int)((char*)p)));
```

Remember to include math.h.

Edit: 
As pointed out in a comment we don't need a double cast. Casting each pointerpointer to an int and then subtracting gives the same answer as the (unecessary) double casting above.

```
printf("%d\n", abs((int)(q) - (int)(p)));
```

Comment: That won't work reliably if sizeof(int) < sizeof(pointer). Either cast to intptr_t or just cast to char*.