# How do I insert a value in an arbitrary position in a block of memory?

Tags: c, memory, pointers

I have two C functions, which basically operate on a stack data structure. This one pushes a value of type `OBJ` which is actually just `unsigned long` to the top of the stack. The stack is also grown if necessary.

```
OBJ Quotation_push_(CzState *cz, CzQuotation *self, OBJ object)
{
    if ((self->size + 1) > self->cap) {
        self->items = (OBJ *)CZ_REALLOC(self->items, sizeof(OBJ) * (self->cap + 1) * 2);
        self->cap = (self->cap + 1) * 2;
    }
    self->items[self->size++] = object;
    return (OBJ)self;
}
```

The next function inserts an `OBJ` into an arbitrary position in the `self->items` array. Try as I might, it just won't work properly. I use `Quotation_push_` here with a dummy value to get the automatic growth behavior. The problem is that I always see the `CZ_NIL` dummy value at the end of the array, with the item I'm trying to insert just overwriting what's in the position already. Here's what I've got so far:

```
OBJ Quotation_insert_(CzState *cz, CzQuotation *self, OBJ object, int pos)
{
    printf("have to move %d OBJ from %d to %d\n", self->size - pos, pos, pos + 1);
    Quotation_push_(cz, self, CZ_NIL);
    memmove(self->items + ((pos + 1) * sizeof(OBJ)), self->items + (pos * sizeof(OBJ)), sizeof(OBJ) * (self->size - pos));
    self->items[pos] = object;
    return (OBJ)self;
}
```

I'm not getting any segfaults or errors, it just doesn't work as expected. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***updated:***

There are two problems, both in the call to `memmove`.

The first is an off-by-one error in the number of bytes that should be moved. The correct number would be:

```
sizeof(OBJ) * (self->size - pos - 1)
```

Omitting the -1 will actually move one too many bytes, placing your new `CZ_NIL` object *past* the end of the buffer.

The second problem is bigger, but more subtle. Adding integers to a pointer causes the compiler to perform [pointer arithmetic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394767/pointer-arithmetic), which automatically accounts for the size of the objects being pointed to. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/759663/pointer-arithmetic-in-c/759676#759676) for details. Here's the short version: `self->items` is an array of `OBJ`, so you don't need to include `sizeof(OBJ)` in the first two arguments to `memmove`.

Putting it all together, the proper function call would look like this:

```
memmove((self->items + pos + 1),
        (self->items + pos),
        sizeof(OBJ) * (self->size - pos - 1));
```