# Array address subtraction in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Pointer Arithmetic In C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/759663/pointer-arithmetic-in-c)

Code:

```
int main() 
{ 
    int a[ ] ={0,1,2,3,4}; 
    char c[ ] = {'s','a','n','j','u'}; 
    printf("%d\n",&a[3]-&a[0]); 
    printf("%d\n",&c[3]-&c[0]); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Why the output comes 3 3 for both, if we consider the difference in addresses they will be         different for both??

Comment: And...what is the point of this? What question are you *really* asking?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In pointer arithmetics, subtraction return the difference not in bytes, but in the pointer's type between two pointers.

So, since the difference in `int`s between `a[3]` and `a[0]` is identical to the difference in `char`s between `c[3]` and `c[0]` - you get the same result for both.

The arithmetics for pointers subtraction operation is something like:

```
type* p1 = ...
type* p2 = ...
p1 - p2 == (((int)p1) - (int(p2))) / sizeof(type)
```