# Subtracting addresses in a 3d array

Tags: c, dev-c++

I created a 3d array

```
a[2][3][2]
```

Now when I try to print

```
printf("%d",a[1] - a[0]);
```

I get 3 as the output.

What I understand is that a[1] gives me the address of a[1][0][0] element and a[0] the address of a[0][0][0].

Let Address of a[0][0][0] is BA then Address of a[1][0][0] is BA + 4*2*3 where 4 byte is the memory space of an integer datatype

I was expecting the result to be 6.

Similarly I tried

```
printf("%d",(&a + 1) - &a);
```

and the output received was 1.

Where am I going wrong?

Edit 1: Entire Code

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    int a[2][3][2] = {{{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}},{{7,8},{9,10},{11,12}}};
    printf("%d",a[1]-a[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Array address subtraction in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9963708/array-address-subtraction-in-c)

Comment: `printf("%d",a[1] - a[0]);` ----> `printf("%p", (void *)(a[1] - a[0]));`

Comment: Provide the entire code, what your doing that will help to follow?

Comment: `a[1]` gives you a pointer to `a[1][0]`, now that has the same address as `a[1][0][0]`, but is it of type `pointer to array of 2 xxx`.

Comment: @LPs - The would be wrong. The result of pointer subtraction (which is what you'll get after all the decay) is a ptrdiff_t, not another pointer.

Comment: Draw it all out on paper, and remember what the type of e.g. `a[0]` and `a[1]` is, and it should be much clearer.

Comment: @StoryTeller Yes, your right.  Do you know a system where it really apply?

Comment: @LPs - Where what applies?

Comment: @StoryTeller Sorry: where `ptrdiff_t` is not `short int`, `int` or `long int`?

Comment: @LPs - It has to be a signed integer type of some sort as per the standard. One would use `%td` to print it however, to be portable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's break the expression `a[1] - a[0]` apart:

`a[1]` - refers to the second [3][2] array.
`a[0]` - refers to the first [3][2] array.

Now, when arrays are used in *most* contexts, they decay into pointers to the first element. So `a[i]` will decay into a pointer to a 2d array `int(*)[2]`.

The difference is calculated in `sizeof(int[2])` as dictated by pointer arithmetic. And you can see that there are 3 units of `int[2]` in the range `[a[0], a[1])`.

Comment: Thank You for breaking and simplifying. I am new to pointer and addresses hence it is really helpful

Comment: a[1] and [0] point to two separate objects. The behavior is undefined as mentioned in 6.5.6 §8 Some similar additional reasoning: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6291590/4082723 ,if I wasn't clear.

Comment: @2501 a[1] decays to a pointer that is one past the end of a[0]. The arithmetic is well defined.

Comment: @2501 - You can consult 6.5.6/9 if my assurance alone is not enough.

Comment: The rule you mentioned says: *When two pointers are subtracted, both shall point to elements of the same array object,
or one past the last element of the array object*. Pointers a[1] and a[0] don't belong to the same array object. They each point to a separate arrays, that both happen to belong to another array `a`, but that doesn't make them the same array object.

Comment: @2501 - `a[0]` decays to a pointer to the start of `a[0]`. `a[1]` decays to a pointer to start of `a[1]`. Since there's no padding, due to `a` itself being an array, `a[1]` decays to a pointer that is exactly one past the end of the array `a[0]`.  They are also pointers to the same type of object, and by 6.5.6/9 the subtraction is allowed. There really is nothing more to it.

Comment: You're forgetting that they are two separate array objects, just like two members of a struct are two separate object and must not be used in pointer arithmetic, otherwise ub.

Comment: @2501 - I'm not forgetting anything. The standard places no prohibitions with regard to how one obtains a pointer to "one past the end" of an array. As long as one uses *that* address, there is no UB. If however, the OP was to subtract non-consecutive elements like `a[2]` and `a[0]`, *then* the behavior would be undefined as you say.

Answer (score 2):

> What I understand is that a[1] gives me the address of a[1][0][0] element and a[0] the address of a[0][0][0].

This is wrong `a[0]` will give the address of the first 2D array. The address of the first 2D array and the address of `a[0][0][0]` might be co-incident, but they are not the same.

Specifically `&a +1` is not equal to `&a[0][0][0] +1`

Comment: This answer would be better if you distinguished between "pointers" (which have types), and "addresses" which are just, well, addresses.  Thus I would phrase it as the *addresses* are the same - but the types are not (and hence subtraction is different).

Comment: @Rishikesh Raje Yes I get that &a + 1 will give me the address of the memory location after the 3d array i.e. &a[2][3][2] + 1. But is it coming 1 because it will consider the complete size of array a in subtraction? Something like if ((BA + 2*3*2*4)-BA))/sizeof(a)