# Char pointer to integer array

Tags: c

```
int main()
{
    int x[] = {1, 2, 3};
    char *p = &x;
    printf("%d", *(p+1));
    return 0;
}
```

I run the code in codeblocks and it is giving 0 as output.
If I I change p as int pointer then its giving 2 as output.

```
int main() 
{    
int x[] = {1, 2, 3}; 
    int *p = &x; 
    printf("%d", *(p+1));
    return 0;
}
```

Why so?

Comment: Because an int is not a char

Comment: `p+1` in the second program is same as `p+4` in the first one. This is because `sizeof(char)` is 1 byte and `sizeof(int)` is 4 bytes.

Comment: `char *p = &x;` is a constraint violation - pay attention to compiler error messages

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pointer Arithmetic In C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/759663/pointer-arithmetic-in-c)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When `p` is declared as a pointer to `char`, it is expected to point at data with size of `1` byte. So `(p + 1)` increments `p` by 1 byte.

Since an `int` is at least 4 bytes long, `(p + 1)` is likely pointing to the second of the higher order bytes of `1`, which is still `0`.

If you wanted it to have identical output, you would do something like that

```
printf("%d\n", *(p + sizeof(int)));
```

But it's best to avoid such code and compile with the `-Wall` flag, which would definitely produce a warning in your case.

Comment: One more thing, as pointer p is containing address of x which itself contains address of first element, then why not *p is printing address of first element which is stored in x?It's printing value of first element.

Comment: When you use the `*` thingy you are referring to the contents of the address, i.e. the value of which the address the pointer is pointing to. That's why it's printing the value. Remove the `*` and use `%p` format to print the address instead.

Answer (score 4):

Assume sizeof(int) is 16 bits. 2 in binary is 00000000 00000010.
sizeof(char) is 8 bits.
Little and big endian are two ways of storing multibyte data-types.

Consider the following code:
    int i = 2;
    char *c = (char*)&i;
    if ((*c)==2)
       printf("Little endian");
    else           //if *c is 0
       printf("Big endian");

From this code you can conclude that Big Endian will store 2 as 00000000 00000010. But Little Endian will store it as 00000010 00000000. , So zero as output would mean first 8 bits are zero, so system is Big Endian. Had it been using Little Endian, answer would be 2 as a char p is supposed to point 8 bits only.
Actually, declaring the data type of pointer means to specify how any bits do you want it to refer and how many bits it will jump when incremented.
If in this example, as p is a char pointer, *(p+1) will refer 00000010 in Big endian and 00000000 in Little Endian.
Your compiler may be using 32 bit for interger, so i think in both cases *(p+1) will give 0. (as 2 => 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000010 2nd byte from either side is 0)

Refer to this: `#include

```
       int main()
      {
        int x[] = {1, 2, 3};
         char *p = &x;
        printf("%d\n", *p);
         printf("%d\n", *(p+1));
          printf("%d\n", *(p+2));
          printf("%d\n", *(p+3));
         printf("%d\n", *(p+4));
          printf("%d\n", *(p+5));
         printf("%d\n", *(p+6));
         printf("%d\n", *(p+7));
          printf("%d\n", *(p+8));
          return 0;
            }`
```

Output:
1
0
0
0
2
0
0
3

Answer (score 2):

When you increment a pointer, it moves by the size of the thing it is pointing to.

Let's say you have 16 bit integers.  In binary, the number one is:   0000 0000 0000 0001

A char pointer can only point to 8 bits at a time: 0000 0000

Comment: To be accurate: A `char`-pointer can only point to `CHAR_BIT`s bits at a time. With `CHAR_BIT` being defined to be at least 8.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Thanks, I corrected my post (and don't call me Shirley)

Answer (score 2):

To have a look from a slightly different angle, about the binary `+` operator, chapter 6.5.6, paragraph 8 of `C99` standard says, [emphasis mine]

> When an expression that has integer type is added to or subtracted from a pointer, the result has the type of the pointer operand. If the pointer operand points to an element of an array object, and the array is large enough, the  ***result points to an element offset from the original element such that the difference of the subscripts of the resulting and original array elements equals the integer expression***. In other words, if the expression P points to the i-th element of an array object, the expressions (P)+N (equivalently, N+(P)) and
>   (P)-N (where N has the value n) point to, respectively, the i+n-th and i−n-th elements of the array object, provided they exist.

So, in your *First case*, `p` is of type `char *` and `(p + 1)` gives a result as a pointer which is incremented by `sizeof(char)`[that's 1 byte, *most* of the cases] and hence points to the 2nd element of the *char array* held by `p`. Since actually, the array held by `p` is of type `int` [Let's say 4 bytes of length, in a 32 bit system], so as per the value stored, [`1` getting stored as `0000 0000 0000 0001`], the `*(p+1)` prints out `0`.

OTOH, in your *second case*, `p` is of type `int *` and `(p + 1)` gives a result as a pointer which is incremented by `sizeof(int)` and hence points to the 2nd element of the *int array* held by `p`. Since actually, the array held by `p` is of type `int`, so as per the value stored, [`int x[] = {1, 2, 3};`], the `*(p+1)` prints out `2`.